# Manusmriti says Sama Veda is impure, whereas Krishna says he is Sama Veda of all the Vedas

Tags: bhagavad-gita, manu-smriti, sama-veda

The Manusmriti [says](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200231.html):

> The Ṛgveda is sacred to the gods and the Yajurveda is human; the
>   Sāmaveda has been declared to be related to the Pitṛs; **hence its sound
>   is impure.**—(124)

This is odd because Krishna says in Bhagavad Gita 10.22:

[image]

Angiras also says in his Dharma Shastra:

> Aṅgiras (Caturvargacintāmani, Paribhaṣa-Kāla, Adhyāya 14).—‘In as much
>   as sacrifices to the deities of the cremation-ground are offered with
>   the Sāmaveda,—**the sound of that Veda is unclean.**’

And also:

> in Smṛticandrikā (Saṃskāra, p. 160), as stating the **reason** for
>   what has been declared in the preceding verse;—in Puruṣārthacintāmaṇi
>   (p. 443);—and in Hemādri (Kāla, p. 768),—in all these to the same
>   effect.

However, Medhatithi says:

> The sound of the Sāmaveda should not he understood, by this, to be
>   really unclean; all that is meant is that, just as Veda should not be
>   recited in the presence of an unclean substance, so should it not he
>   recited in the presence of the Sāma-chant; it is on the ground of this
>   similarity to ‘unclean substances’ that the sound of Sāma has been
>   said to be ‘unclean.’

But what is the point of comparing it to unclean things and even deliberately stating that it's impure, when you don't actually mean it is impure?

Comment: All of the stanzas of the Soma Veda except for 75 are entirely from the RIg Veda. The Soma Veda is only chants used in the Soma sacrifice. As the Soma is used only in the Soma sacrifice, in relation to the Rig and Yajur Veda, they are not as 'clean'. BUT the Soma 'is' Veda. Krishna says that of the vedas He is the Soma because the Soma is the simplest yet most exact of the Vedas.

Comment: Could you provide the original sanskrit versions?

Comment: Does 'sound' is impure mean 'text' is impure?

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Here is the original Sanskrit of the Manusmriti: ṛgvedo devadaivatyo yajurvedastu mānuṣaḥ | 
sāmavedaḥ smṛtaḥ pitryastasmāt tasyāśucirdhvaniḥ || 124 ||

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee The word for "impure" is "asuchi"

Comment: Yes, thats what i asked. Its sound is impure, not that it is impure

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee But when people talk about the Vedas, they refer to the sound of the Vedas, the shabda.

Comment: Shabda means word. Dhwani means sound

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Ok I see now.

Comment: Current title is a statement than a question. The last line should be the question title: "But what is the point of comparing it to unclean things and even deliberately stating that it's impure, when you don't actually mean it is impure?"

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee But almost all of the mantras from the Sama Veda are just extracted from the Rig Veda and set in a musical tone.

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes . And i think vedas can never be impure. something is being misunderstood.